# How can I create a CF compliant netCDF file?

Tags: oceanography, cf-metadata

I have been looking for a proper way to create a netCDF file that is compliant with the **Climate and Forecast (CF) Metadata Convention**. It is amazing that I can find a [compliance checker](http://cf-convention.github.io/compliance-checker.html) for NetCDF files at the CF-Metadata web page, but I have problems to find any tools or methods to create such a file. How can I create a CF-compliant netCDF file? Are there any good tools, which I can use?

Comment: I see that NOAA has posted on their site [NODC NetCDF Templates v1.0](http://www.nodc.noaa.gov/data/formats/netcdf/) the CDL templates, which can be used with NCO commands to create compliant files. I am new to this and I wonder if there is any other preferred ways? Thanks!

Comment: Just follow the documentation and use any NetCDF library of your choice?  I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Isn't netCDF more suited for [gis.stackexchange.com]? [This question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/85722/28519) for example seems similar to me.

Comment: Please don't ask shopping /recommendation questions here. Try [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: @hugovdberg Wouldn't it be like calling anything with a wheel on it a car? It is a machine-independent common data format, so yes there is no reason for GIS to not use it. Nowhere in my question I mentioned GIS. Nevertheless, thank you for the link that you provided. Although not the answer to my question, it is somewhat relevant to one aspect of it. Thumbs up!

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I have edited my question to make clear that I am not asking for a software suggestion specifically, but rather for proper means of doing it. I hope it is clearer now...

Comment: @ZZZ not really, you ask for a tool that creates netCDF, and being a fileformat you're asking for software, and at gis.se all tools for geoinformation management are discussed. Also from your comment it is unclear to me whether you mean GIS as a shortcut for ArcGIS or geoinformation systems in general, because I think the latter is relevant here.

Comment: Without knowing what _exactly_ your requirements are, it's really difficult to know how to answer this question. (Just so you know, in my previous job I installed a utility to make our data NetCDF complient. It was highly customized to our particular dataset. I don't know if a general solution is available or even possible.) If you provide more detail, we might be able to open this question then.

Comment: Hmm. This meta discussion is relevant here: http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/77/would-geosciences-specific-software-support-be-on-topic-here Yes, this could be seen as a recommendation question, but it's also "I have this geoscience-related problem, how do I solve it". We wouldn't object to that if it didn't involve software. I agree with the too-broad aspect, and would welcome the asker giving a specific example of the problem to be solved.

Comment: Not sure if this question is an exact duplicate, but it's pretty similar: http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/1075/what-are-the-guidelines-for-constructing-variable-names-that-follow-cf-conventio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far this has been the most suitable answer to my question...

NOAA's National Oceanographic Data Center has posted NetCDF Templates v1.0 the CDL templates on their [web site](http://www.nodc.noaa.gov/data/formats/netcdf/). These can be used with [netCDF Operator (NCO) commands](http://nco.sourceforge.net/) to create [Climate and Forecast (CF)](http://cf-convention.github.io/index.html) compliant files.

http://www.nodc.noaa.gov/data/formats/netcdf/ 
http://nco.sourceforge.net/ 
http://cf-convention.github.io/index.html