# What are the guidelines for constructing variable names that follow CF conventions?

Tags: models, terminology, cf-metadata

I am attempting to develop variable names following Unidata's climate forecasting (CF) variable naming guidelines, but for biological variables used to parameterize and evaluate land surface and ecosystem models ([See a first draft on Google drive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ai_PDCcY5g2JdEZoSW5KYks1ZHRSdHJIbndoRl8wdWc&usp=sharing#gid=0)). However, I can not find the documentation for these guidelines.

Until early 2014, the guidelines were here: http://cf-pcmdi.llnl.gov/, but now there is a link to http://cfconventions.org/, and then a [list of standard names](http://cfconventions.org/standard-names-26.html), but the [guidelines page](http://cf-pcmdi.llnl.gov/documents/cf-standard-names/guidelines) that this points to does not (currently) exist.

I think it would be helpful here to have a link to the appropriate documentation, but also a summary of the guidelines (i.e., how to construct variable names that are consistent with the CF approach). In addition, any feedback on the standard_name field in my draft would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possible this is not what you need, but here's an archive of the [Guidelines for Construction of CF Standard Names](https://web.archive.org/web/20130728212039/http://cf-pcmdi.llnl.gov/documents/cf-standard-names/guidelines), which is "Version 1, 3 December 2008" and was cached on July 28, 2013; guessing that the page has not been updated since December 2008.

Also, the source code repository for CF Conventions website you linked to ([cf-convention.github.io](http://cf-convention.github.io)) is viewable from [here](https://github.com/cf-convention); if you had questions about the status of the site, you might try contacting the [developer listed on Github for the project](https://github.com/mattben); [their email is listed on their Github profile](https://github.com/mattben).

**UPDATE:** Here's the [contact info for the CEDA Data Scientist](http://home.badc.rl.ac.uk/apamment/); their "main role in CEDA is the development of metadata standards, particularly the CF (Climate and Forecast) metadata conventions."

Comment: thanks, I found them in the [cf-convention/repository-cf/cf-standard-names/trunk/src/guidelines.xml](https://github.com/cf-convention/repository-cf/blob/master/cf-standard-names/trunk/src/guidelines.xml); I also reported this omission as an issue [in the github repository](https://github.com/cf-convention/cf-documents/issues/2)

Answer (score 7):

As a result of @blunders answer, I located the document, and will summarize here:

The general framework for constructing names is:

> [surface] [component] standard_name [at surface] [in medium] [due to process] [assuming condition]

where

- **surface** is a horizontal plane, e.g. `tropopause`, or `sea_level`.

  - Single word surface names go at the beginning; surfaces with more than one name goes after the standard_name
  - `tropopause_stuff`
  - `stuff_at_sea_level`
- **component** is a vector, e.g. `upward`, `northward`, `x`, etc.
- **medium** is, e.g. in_water, in_soil, etc.
- **process** starts with "due_to", e.g. `due_to_longwave_heating`
- **assuming condition** is a conditional assumption, e.g. `assuming_clear_sky`

Other conventions: there are a number of further conventions provided to standardize meaning, e.g. in the construction of standard_names when transformations, special phrases, chemical species, or generic names are used. For example,

- transformations imply a particular form of units, e.g `ratio_of_X_to_Y` implies a specific form for the units (in this case `[x]/[Y]`.
- generic names imply specific units, e.g. `amount` implies `kg/m2`, `area` implies `m2`, etc.
- there are standard spellings for chemical species, e.g. `nitrate`, `carbon_dioxide`
- phrases: `water` refers to H$_2$O in all phases; `wrt` = with respect to, `toa` = top of atmosphere, etc.